# CSS Images Not Working With Code

Tags: html, css

My CSS Code is not working and I need help to finish it.

I need it so that the buttons will stick under my images but the css messed up when putting the button code under the images.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>English - Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/english.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="science.html">Science</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="hosptality & catering.html">Hosptality & Catering</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="leisure & tourism.html">Leisure & Tourism</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="bteccomputing.html">BTEC Computing</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="btecbusiness.html">BTEC Business</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="CV.html">CV</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="english">
    <center><h2>English:</h2></center>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="ofmam">
      <h4>Of Mice and Men:</h4>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="canspe">
        <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cannabis Speech:</h4>
          <div class="canimage" style="width:500%; max-width: 100%;">
  <a href="cannabis speech.html"><img src="images/English/Speech Icon.png" width="332" height="332"/></a></a>
  <p>Click here to find out more about Cannabis.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="ofmamimage" style="width:50%; max-width: 50%;"> 
  <a href="of mice and men.html"><img src="images/English/of_mice_and_men.jpg" width="291" height="448"/></a>
  <p>Click here to find out more about Of Mice and Men.</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
  </div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
      <p><center>Contact Me:</center></p>
      <p><center>11lanjac@abbeyfield.wilts.sch.uk</center></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS for that Code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #40ea3c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #888;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #38cd34;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #40ea3c;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 240px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }

  /*Hovering: 38cd34 - Not Hovering: 40ea3c*/

  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  */
}

.english {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.canspe {
    padding-right: 200px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%
    max-width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.canimage {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 50%
    max-width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.ofmam {
    padding-left: 250px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ofmamimage {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-top: 500px;
}

#footer {
    background:#40ea3c;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you please post your expected result?

Comment: @JordiCastilla My expected result is for the button and speech icon image to be under the cannabis speech sign. Same with the Of Mice and Men.

The footer should be at the bottom

Comment: Because you have used float and wrong structure. Whenever use float:left dont forget to use clear:both after floated div so there won't be issue like this.

Comment: @Leothelion Please could you help me with an code example? I'm new to programming haha

Comment: that does not give us so much... first of all.. **please balance your `html` tags**, after please post a image or chart where you show expected distribution and if you can, please post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks! :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Your confusing me, im new to everything including stackoverflow and whatever this MVCE thing is

Comment: If you read the link it explains exactly what an MVCE is... Please provide an example of what your code is currently doing, and what your expected outcome is. We can't really "visualise" your outcome based on text, unless one of us is a savant..

Comment: @JacobLane **my apologizes and please, don't hesitate to ask if any doubt**, [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a link, there you can find how to prepare a minimal example to help us to see your problem and fix it :)

Comment: @GavinThomas photo posting websites are blocked on the school systems.

Comment: @GavinThomas don't worry bro! Jacob is new and starting at SO many times is so hard... :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla after skim-reading what's on the MVCE page, I have already tested my code before coming here.

Comment: @JordiCastilla hence why I covered what he needed to post.

Comment: @JacobLane You may have, but not everyone on this site has used your exact scenario. Can you post it on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @JacobLane MVCE is much more than this. I will jump to next question. Hope you find answer. My best! :)

Comment: check this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/hk10op6w/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .nav ul
    {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: normal;
        background-color: #40EA3C;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .nav li
    {
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #888888;
    }

    .nav a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        transition: .3s background-color;
    }

    .nav a:hover
    {
        background-color: #38CD34;
    }

    .nav a.active
    {
        background-color: #40EA3C;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .left, .right
    { width: 50%; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px; }

    .left
    { float: left; }

    .right
    { float: right; width: 50%; }

    .clearfix:after
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px)
    {
        .nav li
        {
            width: 240px;
            border-bottom: none;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

        .nav li
        {
            display: table-cell;
            margin-right: -4px;
        }

    }

    .english
    {
        padding-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer
    {
        background: #40EA3C;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: white;
        padding: 25px;;
    }
```

HTML:

```
     <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>English - Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/english.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="about">
                    <a href="science.html">Science</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="hosptality & catering.html">Hosptality & Catering</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="leisure & tourism.html">Leisure & Tourism</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="bteccomputing.html">BTEC Computing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="btecbusiness.html">BTEC Business</a>
                </li>
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="CV.html">CV</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="english">
            <h2>English:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <h4>Of Mice and Men:</h4>
            <a href="cannabis-speech.html"><img src="images/English/Speech Icon.png" width="332" height="332"/></a>
            <p>Click here to find out more about Cannabis.</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h4>Cannabis Speech:</h4>
            <a href="of-mice-and-men.html"><img src="images/English/of_mice_and_men.jpg" width="291" height="448"/></a>
            <p>Click here to find out more about Of Mice and Men.</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                Contact Me:
                <a href="mailto:11lanjac@abbeyfield.wilts.sch.uk">11lanjac@abbeyfield.wilts.sch.uk</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, you can tweak the style. If it works please accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading your codes, i have found so many errors.

- Be careful with tag as you have tag   so check all tags.
- Always give attention to html structure and follow each opening and closing tag and child div should always be in parent div or else those div will go out of box.
- In your code you used container div outside but be in mind always put all body part inside the container which will help you to maintain in small screen.
- Before making any structure make partitions. Use block then put those block in one block for easy to handle like you want one block left then put all left part in left block and right in right block.
- Don't use 170px or higher padding/margin as its not good practis rather then do what i did.. Take two block and give them `float:left` and `float:right`.
- Instead of using tags like  use `text-align:center` in class or as inline(inline means in same line where you want that css.).

I have updated your code and  html part too. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/hk10op6w/1/) and if you are getting any issue or point which you can't understand then let me know. will Love to help you...

And yup, its not pain but its actually gain for future.. :)